# When I take a python string that contains an &, and call upper() it changes the & to &AMP; Why?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

This my first question here so let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

I've just gotten into python, and I'm running into an issue with ampersands and `upper()`. That works just fine:

```
print("a&a".upper())
> A&A
```

However, when taking a string out from a list of strings, and then running `.upper()`, the above will turn to `A &AMP A`. `&AMP` has a semicolon following it, but I could not include it or the whole thing would have been replaced by an `&`. I'm not sure why this is happening sometimes and and not other times. I've even tried using `str()` to make sure that what was coming out of the list was a string.

Comment: "when taking a string out from a list of strings" - You probably took the original string from an URI/HTML source, where `&amp;` is the escaped sequence for an ampersand

Comment: As @wieson points out, this sounds like an encoding issue (also could be XML)... please provide a minimal complete example

Comment: Now that I think about it, the string did from an excel doc that did contain some html. I'll try a search and replace and see if that fixes it. Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just run the following:

```
["a&a"][0].upper().replace("&AMP;", "&")
```

The reason is most likely because Python is somehow doing a replacement of `&amp;` but not `&AMP;` because of the case-sensitivity.